# Why can't get JSON data from PHP?

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a webpage that exposes some public interfaces that are accessed like a simple AJAX call from other pages. Example:

*http://domain1.com/interface/function.php*:

```
$json['result'] = ... // fill with data
$json['ok'] = true;
echo json_encode($json);
```

*http://domain2.com/application.php*:

```
$call = 'http://domain1.com/interface/function.php';
$curl = curl_init($call);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$call_data = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($error);
print_r($call_data);
```

The problem is $call_data is empty. I already try to use *file_get_contents()* and other curl parameters without success. Also, if I change first line in *application.php* by:

```
$call = 'http://www.google.com/';
```

$call_data gets the right file content (Google home page content, of course). More, *curl_error()* doesn't return any error. What's happening? Why?

Comment: Can you show how you are using `curl_error()`? Have you confirmed that calling `http://domain1.com/interface/function.php:` manually in the browser works and gives you some data?

Comment: does the function.php output the content ? if so, do you set a json header ?

Comment: What's the HTTP response code? You can query that using [`curt_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php). Also, you might want to consult the server logs on domain1.com and find out if your request actually "arrives".

Comment: @pekka I've edited the code to show how I'm using Curl error. If I copy this URL in a browser it shows the right content (a JSON array).

Comment: Strange, this looks in order. Could this be a server issue of some kind (Firewall, content filter...)?

Comment: @Rufinus Yes, function shows the content if I use it through browser, but not using Curl. Json header? I suppose I'm not setting a Json header, because I don't know what it's a Json header :) Please, could you explain?

Comment: You first need to use `json_decode()` like `json_decode(curl_exec($curl));`

Comment: It returns `0` or `FALSE`? The latter case may indicate an invalid handle. The former shouldn't happen. Crank up error reporting a bit. I think, the cUrl handle isn't even initialized.

Comment: @Pekka Maybe, I'm now going to see if the apache logs say something as Linus commented

Comment: @Ivan header('Content-type: application/json'); but it should work without.

Comment: @Ivan Linux meant if($call_data === 0) vs. if($call_data === false)

Comment: `http://domain1.com/interface/function.php` require password or authentication to gain access?

Comment: you haven't passworded this directory or added a session/login script have you?

Comment: Password? nothing at all, it's a simple page.
I've been reading the log files and I've seen that the apache server doesn't receive the request. It seems that curl never asks for the page ¿?

Comment: So it's an uninitialized handle. The machine running your script may not be able to resolve the target host.

Comment: @Ivan What about network connection? Can you try to run a bash command of `curl -X GET http://domain1.com/interface/function.php` on domain2.com? (I notice both are located in two different location)

Comment: @ajreal: Good point! It also fails (returns nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing last weekend. 
If you have some htaccess file or similar thing that unifies the url of the service proveider and adds / or makes some kind of redirection this might cause you the problem - both `curl_exec($curl);` and `curl_error($curl);` will be empty strings.

Answer (score -2):

from the PHP `curl_exec` manual:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

are you sure that you've set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true?

Comment: I set this option third line. But, anyway if it doesn't work I suppose the json output will be also displayed, but nothing (neither if I debug it).

Comment: ah, sorry haven't noticed that